# How is botocore definition data generated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I have been using botocore's definitions ([ec2 example](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data/ec2/2016-11-15)) for a while and I find them very useful. I'd like to know how are these definitions generated.

Comment: Amazon uses this tool, which they recently open sourced: https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/